# Ugly fonts with nVidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, fonts, antialiasing

Just installed nVidia binary drivers today and the fonts are ugly. I've been using the opensource nouveau drivers all this while and the font's were much better. Even the expo effect in compiz was crisp, but now with the binary drivers the fonts look jagged and ugly and the effects not as smooth(which is surprising as the effects use 3d acceleration). The difference is not much but long hours of work makes my eyes hurt.

I primarily installed the binary driver for VDPAU in order to play 1080p videos which do work better now. Even games run faster(but I don't play games that much.

Is there a way to get better font rendering with the nVidia binary drivers as the nouveau drivers do. It's probably some antialiasing setting that I can't seem to find.

Thanks in advance!